# How to create Global Functions like Print?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter there is a [`print` function](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/print.html) that is called along any part of your project files without importing any package.

Can I define a global function like this (in an individual file)?  I don't want to import anything.

Answer (score 3):

**`print`** is part of the [`dart:core` library](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/dart-core-library.html) and this library is *imported automatically*.

This means that you can think of every Dart file really having a "hidden" import statement at the start:

```dart
import 'dart:core';
```

### Can I define a global function like this?

**No**, you cannot because nothing in the `dart:core` library is "global" either, it is just globally imported automatically.

It was simply a decision made to include `print` in the core library alongside standard types like `String`, `List` etc.

### Why?

You say that you "don't want to import anything", however, it is just the way Dart works: you will have to import the libraries you want to use.

Having said that, you should just import the library your function is in normally, however, parts might be interesting to you.

#### Workaround: Parts

The idea you have is *kind of* part of Dart.

In Dart you can split up your *library* (which is practically a single Dart file) into multiple files. At compile time, these multiple files will be merged into a single file again.

For this you can use the `part` directive:

- In the main file of your library, you will have to add `part '{other_file}.dart';`. Note that this main file is **the only place** in your library you can have `import`-statements.
- In all of your other files that are part of your library, you will have to add `part of '{library}.dart';`.
  As I said, the drawback here is that you cannot *import* anything in these part files.

[Learn more](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages#organizing-a-library-package) (the documentation discourages you to use the part directive).