# Dart - How to access global scope?

Tags: flutter, dart, scope, global

The simple actual question is

> How to access GLOBAL scope in Dart?

---

Below is just the answer why I'm looking for it.

I have a problem which requires me to learn about Dart's scope resolution from [here](https://dart.dev/) but unfortunately I can't find the solution for my problem, not even from Google or here, which was surprising me to have to open this question.

Dart allows user to exclude the `this.` on member variable access within class's scope so if two potentially conflicted variables need to share the same name, they need to be differentiated with scope operator and reference.

I need to define a class with member variable `print` where there is also global function `print` being called somewhere within the class. Of course `print() => print(...)` will returns error so I'm expecting something as simple as `print() => global.print(..)` but neither that is working.

I know there's workaround to solve it but please I need a straightforward one if any. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this post will answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57509790/how-to-create-global-functions-like-print

Comment: @JulianModlinski oh i see. so that means i can scope it if i alias the dart:core, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add this line at the top of your file:

```
import 'dart:core' as core;
```

Then you would be able to refer to print as `core.print(...);`

The problem is that now you would have to use `core.` for every primitives like `int`, example:

```
core.int variable = 1;
```

I think this is not worth it and it's better to use another name for your print method.

Comment: i guess there's no better answer. but i decide to alias the function like this print() => global_print()

Comment: @stackunderflow There is a better answer.  See the linked duplicate.

Comment: @jamesdlin i see. thanks a lot. clearly that's the answer i was looking for. my bad to overlooked it